# how to know the right size of /boot

Tags: linux, rhel, boot, initramfs, initrd

for now /boot on our linux machines is

```
/dev/sda1                 497M  157M  340M  32% /boot
```

we want to create a new linux redhat template

and I have the feeling that /boot size is too small

for example as I know kdump use /boot and need space under /boot for this

so is it right to increase the /boot to 1G ?

Comment: If you 'can afford' spending 1 GiB on the boot partition, there is no problem :-)

Comment: Don't give it its own partition; grub supports ext4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RHEL 7, Red Hat recommends that the `/boot` partition be set to at least 1 GiB in size. This is documented in the Installation Guide, [Section 8.14.4.4: Recommended Partitioning Scheme](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-disk-partitioning-setup-x86#sect-recommended-partitioning-scheme-x86)

Quote:

> `/boot` partition - recommended size at least 1 GiB
>
> The partition mounted on `/boot` contains the operating system kernel,
>   which allows your system to boot Red Hat Enterprise Linux, along with
>   files used during the bootstrap process. Due to the limitations of
>   most firmwares, creating a small partition to hold these is
>   recommended. In most scenarios, a 1 GiB boot partition is adequate.
>   Unlike other mount points, using an LVM volume for `/boot` is not
>   possible - `/boot` must be located on a separate disk partition.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "right size" for a filesystem that will cover every specific need, though in most systems it is recommended a minumum of 500MB in /boot (for recovery purposes I think, like booting with 2-3 previous versions of the kernel).

500MB should be fine but if you are in doubt and you have enough space, give it 1GB. There is no way that giving it more space can harm your system.